# Strings look the same but not equal in Bash

Tags: bash, sed

In the following sequence of commands, why does the second `if` not evaluate to true?

```
[m1@qa-node11:~]a="true"
[m1@qa-node11:~]if [ "$a" = "true" ]; then  echo "hi5"; fi
hi5
```

The above `if`, as expected, evaluated to `true`. But...

```
[m1@qa-node11:~]a=$(head -n 1 $CLUSTERS_CONF | grep secure= | sed 's/^.*secure=//' | sed 's/ .*$//')
[m1@qa-node11:~]echo $a
true
[mapr@qa-node11:~]if [ "$a" = "true" ]; then  echo "hi5"; fi
[mapr@qa-node11:~]
```

Why does this `if` not evaluate to `true`?

I even checked to see if `$a` had any extra non-printable characters

```
[mapr@qa-node11:~]echo "'"$a"'"
'true'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: change your 2nd `echo $a` to `echo "$a"XYZ` and see if there are trailing whitespace on  your value of `$a`. Good luck.

Comment: Add `set -x` to your bash shell, then rerun the commands.  `set -x` shows what the shell actually interprets and is a common way to debug bash/ksh shell scripts.

Comment: Run `echo "$a" | hexdump -C` and let's see what you get

Comment: Try: `if [ $a = "true" ];` instead of `if [ "$a" = "true" ];`

Comment: You can also use `declare -p a` to get a better idea of the actual contents of the variable (although `bash` still doesn't display strings containing carriage returns clearly).

Comment: `printf '%q\n' "$a"` is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this observation:

> ```
> [mapr@qa-node11:~]echo "'$a'"
> 'true'
> [mapr@qa-node11:~]if [ "$a" = "true" ]; then echo "hi5"; fi
> [mapr@qa-node11:~]
> ```

It is evident that `$a` contains something invisible.

A good way to see invisible characters is using the `hexdump` tool.
For example, if the value really is simply "true",
we should see this:

```
$ printf true | hexdump -C
00000000  74 72 75 65                                       |true|
00000004
```

You can filter out non-alphabetic characters using the `s/[^a-z]//g` command with `sed`:

```
a=$(head -n 1 $CLUSTERS_CONF | grep secure= | sed -e 's/^.*secure=//' -e 's/ .*$//' -e 's/[^a-z]//g')
```

Btw this pipeline can be simplified:

```
a=$(sed -ne 's/[^a-z]//g' -e 's/^.*secure=//p' -e 1q "$CLUSTERS_CONF")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The hexdump clearly shows the problem.

Comment: @KarthikM If this helped you, then perhaps you could mark my answer accepted? (see the pipe icon below the voting buttons)

Comment: Marking as accepted. The hexdump helped me find that something is wrong with the way I am reading and filtering the line from the conf file. 

BUT the two sed filters that you have provided don't work.

`[m1@qa-node11:~]a=$(head -n 1 $CLUSTERS_CONF | grep secure= | sed -e 's/^.*secure=//' -e 's/ .*$//' -e 's/[^a-z]//g')
[m1@qa-node11:~]echo $a
mtrue
[m1@qa-node11:~]a=$(sed -ne 's/[^a-z]//g' -e 's/^.*secure=//p' -e 1q "$CLUSTERS_CONF")
[m1@qa-node11:~]echo $a

[m1@qa-node11:~]`

The data in the conf file is
foo.dev.cluster.com secure=true qa-node100.qa.lab:2222

Comment: @KarthikM would it be possible to upload the file somewhere so I can download and inspect it? Also, are you doing this in Git Bash, or in Windows, or in Linux?